# SQL Server - grab part of string after a value sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Note` with a column named `Notes`.

```
Notes
------
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\fs20 called insurance company they are waiting to hear from the claimant's attorney
```

It has font info in the beginning which I don't need.  I've created a new column name `final_notes` and would like to grab everything after the "fs" plus two characters.  The final result would be

```
final_notes
-----------
 called insurance company they are waiting to hear from the claimant's attorney
```

Comment: And how is this format defined, how do you propose to identify where to start? Does every row have the same amount of characters before the `fs`, or are we looking for the first `fs` in the string? There appears to be a space after `fs20` do you want that also?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: @Charlieface yes I'm looking for the first `fs`.  I like the idea of also grabbing the space after `fs20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `PATINDEX` to find the first occurrence of `fs` followed by two digits.

We null it out if we get a `0` i.e. we cannot find the string.

```sql
SUBSTRING(Note, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%fs[0-9][0-9]%', Note), 0) + 4, LEN(Note))
```

Comment: thanks for your help so far.  I tried doing this but got an error. 
`update note 
set final_notes = SUBSTRING(Notes, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%fs[0-9][0-9]%', Notes), 0) + 4, LEN(Notes))` 

The error is 
`Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is using a deprecated column type. You should be using `n/varchar(max)`. Be that as it may, you can use `DATALENGTH` to get the length of a `text` column